# How are notifications carried in JAVA?

Tags: java, events, notifications

I was reading about the Event Style architecture and came across this

> There are different ways to deliver notifications, but the most common
>   technique uses an indirect method call that is made through a pointer
>   initialized at runtime.

But when Java does not have pointers how does it deliver the notifications ?

Comment: Java has pointers just fine, just no pointer arithmetic (which you don't need for this and for many other things) and they call them references. No function pointers, but polymorphism.

Comment: What Delnan said -- Java does most certainly have pointers -- it just calls them "references".

Answer (score 1):

Java's event system is based on the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern, except in Java Swing, everything is called a "listener" instead of "observer", and typically implements [`EventListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html) (as you can tell from the beast at the top of that link).

For example, a component such as a `JButton` allows you to add listeners to it that care about when something happens with the button. If your listener cares about button clicks, you would add an `ActionListener` to the button, and `JButton` adds it to an internal list to be used later (specifically, it uses `EventListenerList`). When the user clicks the button, the `JButton` class will "fire" an event to all of the `ActionListener` implementations that have been registered with it.

This is basically the observer pattern because you have a subject that's being observed (the `JButton`) and an observer that wants to be notified about the subject's changes or events (the `ActionListener`).

Java doesn't have pointers, per se, but that doesn't mean that this can't be accomplished. In C++, you would pass a function pointer to the subject, and the subject would just call that function. Since Java doesn't have function pointers, you pass an object that implements a particular interface to the subject, and the subject will call an exact method on the interface. In the example above, this would be the `ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` method.

Note that this method is also popular among other Java libraries besides Swing because of the absence of mechanisms like function pointers and the prevalence of Java interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Java Swing uses listeners to deliver notifications about events.

Here's a snippet of code from a Swing class

```
        Font font = model.getActivityFont();
        activityTextFontButton = new JButton(getFontText(font));
        activityTextFontButton.setFont(font);
        activityTextFontButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                JFontChooser fontChooser = new JFontChooser();
                fontChooser.setSelectedFont(model.getActivityFont());
                int result = fontChooser.showDialog(dialog);
                if (result == JFontChooser.OK_OPTION) {
                    Font font = fontChooser.getSelectedFont();
                    String text = getFontText(font);
                    model.setActivityFont(font);
                    activityTextFontButton.setText(text);
                    activityTextFontButton.setFont(font);
                    JButton dummy = new JButton(text);
                    setButtonSizes(activityTextFontButton, 
                            connectorTextFontButton, dummy);
                    dialog.validate();
                    dialog.pack();
                }
            }
        });
```

When the button is pressed, the JButton class executes the code that's part of the ActionListener.  That's because the JButton class has a reference to the ActionListener instance and knows that the method to execute is actionPerformed.

There are other ways in Java to drive events (see the Observer / Observed classes), but listeners are a pretty cool way to deliver notifications about events.

Comment: And the listener is addressed by a "reference", which in any other language would be called a "pointer".